# Why is regex not matching on unicode character

Tags: c#, regex

So I am trying to write a regex in c# (.NET) to match on a range of unicode characters that could potentially be found in a string.  As a simple test, I attempted to match on a single unicode character, \u8221, which is the character ”.  If I use the regex string "”", I get a match against my test string that contains this character.  If, however, I change my regex to "\u8221", I don't get a match.  Anyone know why this could be and how to get it to work?  I have been pulling my hair out over this one.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: *All* characters in .NET are Unicode. Please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - it's not clear (at least to me) from your description.

Comment: are you using a verbatim literal? i.e. var pattern = @"\u8221" or are you just using a regular literal - var pattern = "\u8221" - you should try the verbatim literal approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not matching the correct character.  [`\u` requires a character code in hexadecimal](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet).  Try `\u201D` instead.

Comment: Actually, I think it's `\u0022`.  Verified on regexhero

Comment: @David, this is my source: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm.  `\u0022` is a standard quotation mark, while she wants to match a right closing quotation mark.

Comment: I tried both on regexhero and only \u0022 matched.  Here's my [source](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22/index.htm).

Comment: Ah - ok.  I see what you mean now.  I guess I need to put my glasses on :-)

Comment: @David The character in question is U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, not U+0022 QUOTATION MARK, the clue is that U+201D curls in as property typographic quotes do, not the nasty straight thing that ASCII has.

Comment: You nailed it.  That was it.  Now I feel like a dufus.  Many thanks!